# Creating a new window on button click - Vaadin14

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to create a new Window using:

```
final Window window = new Window("Window");
this.getUI().addWindow(window);
```

This is from the Vaadin homepage https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/window

But unfortunately my IDE is showing the following error:
The constructor Window(String) is undefined.

When i delete the string, it says: the constructor Window() is not visible.

Why is that? In the vaadin demo it works just fine.

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: The eclipse distribution Rapidclipse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no `Window` class in Vaadin 14**.

The demo page you linked in the question is about Vaadin 8.

In Vaadin Flow (Vaadin 10+), the [Dialog](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-dialog/java-examples) is used instead of the old `Window`. It's not exactly the same as the old `Window` - for example the `Dialog` has no maximize or close button automatically. But along with other components you want to show within that `Dialog`, you can add for example a button that will close the dialog when clicked. Or let the dialog close when the user clicks outside it using `dialog.closeOnOutsideClick(true);`

Edit: go check out this vaadin blog post of a good looking `Dialog` example, with video (and code is also linked there): https://vaadin.com/blog/new-component-features-and-development-time-improvements-in-vaadin-14

Comment: Can i display another ui in a dialog?

Comment: Yes you can display whatever you like in a Dialog. add as many components as you like. The window in the sampler that you linked can definitely be made using a Dialog.

Answer (score -2):

The `Window` class is part of the Vaadin-Framework. It doesn't exist like that in rapidclipse and other IDE's. You have to write your own `Window` class (by extending `Panel`) or you can copy the `Window` class from their github.

refer to:
https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/ui/Window.java

You are getting this error, because you are trying to access the `Window` class of the rapidclipse framework, which apparently has no constructor and is meant for something else.

Comment: What is the easiest way to create of window that contains another ui?

Comment: The `Window` class you link to is for `Vaadin Framework`, which Vaadin version < 10. There is no Window class in Vaadin Flow

Comment: creating your own `Window` class by extending `Panel` is going to be difficult (read: impossible), seeing how `Panel` is also not a Vaadin Flow Component.